# Removing an element of the linked list that contains a letter that user inputs

Tags: c, file, linked-list

I need to make a function that removes elements of a linked list (elements of the list are words) that contain a letter the user inputs. Basically, I have a .txt file that has random words in it, after loading the words into the linked list, I need to make several functions (this post is only dedicated for the 4th function from the menu), one of which is the function I'm having trouble with.

My idea was to make a separate function that will send 1 if the word contains the letter and 0 if it does not, then I made a function that goes through my linked list and using the first function checks if that element of the list contains the word, if it does then I remove it and move onto the next element.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Element Element;

struct Element
{
    char word[50];
    Element *next;
};

Element *load_file(Element *head)
{
    char file[500];
    scanf("%s", file);

    Element *temp = head;

    FILE* fp = fopen(file, "r");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error while loading file.");
        return 0;
    }

    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        Element *newE = (Element*)malloc(sizeof(Element));

        fscanf(fp, "%s", newE->word);

        newE->next =  NULL;

        if(!temp)
        {
            head = temp = newE;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next = newE;
            temp = newE;
        }

    }

    fclose(fp);
    printf("\nFile loaded successfully\n");

    return head;
}

int frequency(Element *head, char *word)
{
    Element *temp = head;
    int counter = 0;

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(temp->word, word) == 0)
        {
            counter++;
        }

        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return counter;
}

int contains(char word[], char letter)
{
    int end = strlen(word);
    int flag = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < end-1; i++)
    {
        if(letter == word[i])
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    return flag;
}

Element *delete_word(Element *head, char letter)
{
    Element *temp = head;
    Element *before = NULL;
    Element *newHead = head;

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        if(contains(temp->word, letter))
        {
            if(before == NULL)
            {
                newHead = temp->next;
                free(temp);
                temp = newHead;
            }
            else
            {
                before->next = temp->next;
                free(temp);
                temp = before->next;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            before = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    return newHead;
}

void printElement(Element *element)
{
    printf("%s \n", element->word);
}

void printList(Element *head)
{
    Element *temp = head;

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printElement(temp);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void meni()
{
    printf("************** MENI **************\n");
    printf("1. Loading text from file \n");
    printf("2. Print all elements of the list \n");
    printf("3. Frequency of a certain word \n");
    printf("4. Delete words that contain a letter \n");
    printf("5. Load the list into a file \n");
    printf("6. Exit \n\n");
}

int main()
{
    Element *head = NULL;

    int option;

    while(1)
    {
        meni();

        scanf("%d", &option);

        switch(option)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                printf("Input a name of the file: \n");
                head = load_file(head);
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                printList(head);
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                char word[100];

                printf("Input a word: ");

                scanf("%s", word);

                int num = frequency(head, word);

                printf("%d\n", num);
                break;
            }
            case 4:
            {
                char word[100];

                printf("Input a word: ");

                scanf("%s", word);

                head = delete_word(head, word);

                printList(head);

                break;
            }
            case 5:
            {

            }
            case 6:
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, it makes no changes on the list whatsoever.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", file);`   This will NOT read in the whole file.  The input format specifier: `%s` stops when any white space is encountered.  So, only the first word will be read.  Also, the specifier: `%s` doesn't know anything about the input buffer length and does append a NUL byte to the input.   (in this case) any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.  Therefore, The code should look similar to: `if( scanf(scanf("%99s", file) != 1 ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf to read word from file failed\n" );`

Comment: regarding: `Element *delete_word(Element *head, char letter)`  the second parameter will be the address of the array `word[]`, not a character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `delete_word()` function is declared as:

```
Element *delete_word(Element *head, char letter);
```

But you call it with a `char*`:

```
char word[100];
head = delete_word(head, word);
```

The menu option says `Delete words that contain a letter` but when the user selects that option, he/she is instructed to `Input a word:` (confusing).

You then send the address of the first `char` in `word` to the function. From that address one `char` is picked. It'll be random at best and it will most probably corrupt the stack (since you, by picking one `char` only, probably pick 1 byte out of 4 or 8).

You could make it work like this:

```
    case 4:
    {
        char word[100];

        printf("Input characters: ");

        if(scanf("%s", word)==1) {
            int len = strlen(word);
            for(int i=0; i<len; ++i) {
                head = delete_word(head, word[i]);
            }
        }

        printList(head);

        break;
    }
```

This would allow the user to enter some characters and all words containing any of those would be removed.